# Method not found after adding code class to SharePoint Web Part

Tags: 2010, web-part, development

I'm creating a SharePoint Web Part that displays list items.

To display these items I am using an `asp:ListView` and `<%#Eval() %>`.
I needed to change the output of `<%#Eval() %>` so I added a new static class to the project, created an extension method and imported the namespace in the user control.

So the `<%#Eval() %>` looks like this: `<%#Eval("xxx").ToString().MyMethod() %>`

The problem is that when I debug this Web Part I get an error saying that 'string' does not contain a definition for MyMethod.

Comment: `<%# ClassName.MyMethod() %>` this doesn't work? or `<%# NameSpace.ClassName.MyMethod() %>`

Comment: I have imported the namespace like this:<%@ Import Namespace="MyClassNamespace"%> and used my method like this: <%#Eval("xxx").ToString().MyMethod() %>

Comment: Moussa, try not to call extension method directly... First call a method in your page class and then return the output of Extension Method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try it different way:

- In your ascx.cs file, declare a public method

```
public string Abc(DataRowView row) {
return  row["xxx"].ToString().MyMethod()
}
```

- call this function from list view like:

```
<%# Abc(Container.DataItem) %>
```

This should work.

Comment: I agree, sometimes the best way is to simplify the namespace evaluating for asp and just give it one method to call which does the rest of the logic itself.